# Approximate this equation using recursion 4 * (1 - (1 /3 ) + (1 / 5) - (1 / 7) + (1 / 9) - (1 / 11) ... )

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

How would I approximate the following equation using recursion? Here is an iterative approach:

```
def calculateFrac(num):
    result = 0
    for i in range(num):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            result = result + 1 / (2 * i + 1)
        else:
            result = result - 1 / (2 * i + 1)
        print(4 * result)

print(calculateFrac(10))
```

Comment: You forgot the / on the second result. You also forgot to return the result

Comment: Sorry I don't mean to be rude, I just want to get a better understanding of recursion and apply it to this particular example. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @FanonX I see. If you want to learn recursion, you should grab a better example. Because this is something you would typically not solve with recursion in an imperative language. Learning recursion is also about learning when *not* to use it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are also not returning the result. Here is a fixed version of your code.

```
def calculateFrac(num):
    result = 0
    for i in range(num):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            result = result + 1 / (2 * i + 1)
        else:
            result = result - 1 / (2 * i + 1)

    return result # return the result instead of printing it

print(calculateFrac(10)) # 0.7604599047323508
```

From there, the above code is perfectly fine.

### Do not use recursion

Although, note that infinite series are better represented with a `sum` and a `generator`, not recursion. Especially in Python which does not optimize [tail-recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion).

A recursive solution will be slower, use more memory and eventually hit the maximum recursion depth.

```
from itertools import islice, count

def seq():
    for n in count():
        yield (-1) ** n / (2 * n + 1)

print(sum(islice(seq(), 0, 10))) # 0.7604599047323508
```

### Recursion practice

It seems you want to learn to use recursion. It is thus important you also identify problems where recursion is not necessary of efficient.

Recursion is usually more suited with problems that branch out at every iteration. That is problems of the form *F(N) = F(N<sub>1</sub>) + F(N<sub>2</sub>)* where *N<sub>1</sub>* and *N<sub>2</sub>* are subsets of *N*. A common example would be [mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

You can find [many problem sets for such problems online](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion-practice-problems-solutions/).

Comment: The question is about solving the equation using _recursion_.

Comment: @Mankalas My answer is about the fact this is a bad idea in Python, and I'm giving a good explanation why.

Comment: Awesome, i greatly appreciate your answer!

Comment: @FanonX I'm glad it does. Enjoy practicing recursion!

Answer (score 2):

```
def calculateFraction(num):
  if (num > 0):
    return (-1)**(num) * 1/(num*2+1) + calculateFraction(num-1)
  else:
    return 1

print(4 * calculateFraction(10))
```

**EDIT**

Olivier's answer is extremely good, I wish I could upvote it several times.

In light of that I thought the OP may benefit from seeing a binary implementation of the above approach.  That is to say, whenever recursing, send half the problem to one branch and the other half to another branch.  *(This means that, for example, asking for num=15 will result in a depth of 4 rather than a depth of 16.)*

```
import inspect

def calculateFraction(num, end=0):
    result = 0
    depth = 'Depth({:d}){:s}>'.format(len(inspect.stack())-1, '='*(len(inspect.stack())-1)*2)

    # If there are an odd number of parts to calculate, do the highest one now
    if (((num-end+1)&1) == 1):
        result += ((-1)**(num)) / (num*2+1)
        print('{:s} Fraction part {:d} = {:f}'.format(depth, num, result))
        num-=1

    # If there are still any parts to calculate, do them recursively
    # (There must be an even number, as we did the odd one previously)
    # (That may leave 0 still to do, in which case the recursion is skipped)
    if (num > end):
        mid = ((num-end)>>1) + end

        # Do the upper half of the remaining parts
        print('{:s} Recursing to {:d},{:d}'.format(depth, num, mid+1))
        result += calculateFraction(num, mid+1)

        # Do the lower half of the remaining parts
        print('{:s} Recursing to {:d},{:d}'.format(depth, mid, end))
        result += calculateFraction(mid, end)

    return result

print('Result: {:f}'.format(4*calculateFraction(10)))
```

Comment: @cdlane : 0 returns 1.  1 returns -1/3+1.  2 returns 1/5-1/3+1.  3 returns -1/7+1/5-1/3+1.  I'm not sure that it's wrong, it's just base 0 where you expected base 1.  That made it easier to get the alternating minus sign.  Still, there could be errors, I wrote it on my phone at 2am, but I don't Think they're the errors you describe.

Comment: You're right, I was too focused on matching the output of Oliver's solution and didn't look at the math itself.  Our solutions are simply out of phase with respect to the argument.  Interesting binary implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm asking how would I solve this using recursion.

I don't disagree with @OlivierMelançon about this being a poor example for recursion. I'm providing just one possible implementation of the dreaded recursive solution:

```
def calculateFrac(num):
    if num < 1:
        return 0.0

    return calculateFrac(num - 1) + (2 * (num % 2) - 1) / (2 * num - 1)

print(calculateFrac(10))  # 0.7604599047323508 (put in the 4 *)
```

On my system the largest argument this can handle is 997 without explicitly expanding the call stack via `sys.setrecursionlimit()`.  Using memoization techniques won't help.  We can probably make a tail-recursive solution by doing something like:

```
def calculateFrac(num, sum=0.0):
    if num < 1:
        return sum

    return calculateFrac(num - 1, sum + (2 * (num % 2) - 1) / (2 * num - 1))

print(calculateFrac(10))  # 0.7604599047323506 (put in the 4 *)
```

Not that Python cares about such things. But if it did do tail-call optimization, then such as solution could be as fast as the iterative solutions and not have any stack limitations.

Comment: Just a note to re-iterate my comment on my answer.  Passing 9 to my function gives the exact same result as passing 10 to your function.